# JQuery UI Resiable by bottom-right corner

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-resizable

I want to resize a DIV by dragging its bottom right corner.

What I want is:

- have access to animation, helper, axis, containment options.

I saw the implementation based on JQuery *draggable*, but my understanding is that I'm going to lose all *resizable* options, which are extremely handy.

- use just jquery UI w/out custom plugins.**

I'm sure there's a bunch of them, but I have to stick with JQuery UI.

- hide NS/WE icons, so it'll be resized by dragging top-right corner only (that's an easy part, I can probably figure it out myself)

Could anyone suggest on if *resizable* is adoptable for my scenario or I have to search elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

css has a [resize property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp)

not supported by IE but might work for you...

Comment: what about axis, containment, handle & animation?

Comment: could you clarify what you are trying to do with those properties? jquery ui resizable has an animation option. you could probably restrict containment with the resize event...not really sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: your answer is just a comment... I need to get support for the stuff I enlisted above, just read JQuery UI help please.